# Double AND Where Clause with between Dates

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query like this

```
WHERE Category = 'Freezing' OR Category ='Ooredoo FTTH fault'OR Category ='Ooredoo TT fault ' OR Category ='No Picture'
```

but i want use this date search query with the above code,
im able to use any 1  of this code but im unable to use both query, i have used "AND" or "OR" But its Not working,

````
ScheduleDate BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  ```
````

Comment: What does 'NOT WORKING' mean???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a or b or c and d` is ambiguous. You need to use parenthesis to make it explicit how to group the ands and ors. If you want `category` to match ANY of the options AND the schedule is between certain dates. `(a or b or c) and d`.

```
where (
    Category = 'Freezing' or
    Category = 'Ooredoo FTTH fault' or
    Category = 'Ooredoo TT fault ' or
    Category = 'No Picture'
  )
  and ScheduleDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

(Note: Do not use string concatenation to put values into queries, especially not straight from user input. It's a security hole and can cause errors. Use [bind parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).)

(Note: You have an extra space in one of your options.)

You can also use [`in`](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_in.asp) to make the query simpler.

```
where
  Category in (
    'Freezing', 'Ooredoo FTTH fault', 'Ooredoo TT fault', 'No Picture'
  )
  and ScheduleDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Of course, he means that precedence rules for `or` and `and` are ambiguous for we people, not computers ;-)